# How to run R script from RGUI using Rscript command?

Tags: r, rjava

I am trying to run R script using RGui using Rscript command. It throws me error saying Error: object 'Rscript' not found. I am able to run this script from command prompt successfully. What I need to set in RGui to make it run??
[image: Screen shot for the same]

Comment: `Rscript` needs to be used from the system command prompt, not at the R command prompt. `source()` seems to do what you need.

Comment: thanks for response,this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to enter the full path using script and double backslash to escape various characters such as "\U" in "C:**\U**sers" for example.

source("C:\\.R")

Like this.